# Redirections and some content cannot be viewed

Tags: views, caching

I´m new here. My site is built in Drupal 6.20. It is sending a 403 page for section content that has been published for a while. It seems that some redirections have disappeared as well although I can see them in the database.

I´m wondering whether it is a problem with the Global Redirect Module, or/and the views pages...I can´t see content from a specific type of view.

Can anybody help? Thanks a milliom